# Is python's builtin sort parallelized?

Tags: python, sorting

Will python automatically parallelize sorting across all cores?

Sorting a list of objects based on an integer property, which sorts a list of size 2M in ~1.7s. My machine has 16 logical cores and 4 GPUs which I would like to leverage to speedup the sort. I found a couple parallel merge sort implementations online but none seemed popular which is surprising given the parallel hardware available today. Would these implementations be better on machines with 8-16 cores?

Comment: no its not ... theres probably a library out there that can help ... numpy will at least do it at the c level ... how big is this list you need sorted? could you just store it sorted then do binary search to insert?

Comment: No, builtin `sorted()` or `list.sort()` is not parallelized, because the sorting method it uses (TimSort) is not parallelizable. You can implement your own parallelized sorting algorithm using parallel merge sort or some other algorithm, or google search for someone else's attempt (such as [this github gist I found by searching "parallelized sorting python" on google](https://gist.github.com/stephenmcd/39ded69946155930c347))

Comment: It's not really possible to parallelize a sort of arbitrary Python objects under the GIL. Sorting performs comparisons constantly, and each comparison must hold the global interpreter lock.

Comment: Please, ask only one question per question. Also, note that your second question is too broad and opinion-based, and will need *at least* a precise, unambiguous, objectively measurable definition of "simplest" as well as a demonstration of what you have tried so far, where you failed, what you tried to get unstuck, and why that didn't work.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Do the comparisons `sorted` makes need to lock the interpreter if `sorted` is implemented at the CPython level?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: Each comparison invokes arbitrary comparison hooks that are not under the control of the sort implementation, and each comparison involves accessing *memory* that other threads could write to.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Is that really true for [unsafe_long_compare](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c0eed7375fdd791cc5e19ceabfab4170ad44062/Objects/listobject.c#L2085) etc?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Why is Timsort not parallelizable?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This method doesn't really perform very well due to the overhead of copying memory around (among other reasons) and the slowness of the built-in `heapq.merge` operation. I suggest just using `numpy.ndarray.sort()` if possible since it's surprisingly quick.

---

A simple method for parallelizing to `n` threads is to split your collection into `n` equal pieces, and then feed each chunk into a separate thread. Once the threads are done, collate their sorted results into one list via a stable merge operation.

```
from heapq import merge
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def sort_parallel(xs, n_workers):
    pool = Pool(n_workers)
    pos = [i * len(xs) // n_workers for i in range(n_workers + 1)]
    xss = [xs[i:j] for i, j in zip(pos[:-1], pos[1:])]
    pool.map(sort_inplace, xss)
    return list(merge(*xss))

def sort_inplace(xs):
    xs.sort()
```

Comment: I tried the code, didn't work, the result isn't sorted. I think `sort_inplace` needs to return `xs` and then you need `xss = pool.map(...)`. And instead of `merge` you could concatenate the pieces and use `.sort()`, that's much faster.

Comment: [Working version](https://repl.it/repls/ScrawnyIllStartups#main.py).

Answer (score 0):

> Will python automatically parallelize sorting across all cores?

There is nothing in the Python Language Specification (or more precisely, the Python Standard Library Specification) that would prevent an implementor from parallelizing either `list.sort()` or `sorted()`. There is, however, also nothing in the Python Language Specification or the Python Standard Library Specification that would *force* an implementor to parallelize either `list.sort()` or `sorted()`.

Therefore, it is completely up to each implementation whether they implement them serial, parallel, or print out the list, fax it to Malaysia, and have it hand-sorted in a sweat shop. Also, an implementation is free to change the implementation strategy at any time without warning, as long as it does not violate the invariants guaranteed by the Library Specification. (Which is basically only that the result must be sorted and that the sort must be stable.)

Or, to answer the question succinctly:

> Will python automatically parallelize sorting across all cores?

You can't know.